# Should I align the grout lines of the tile edging with the grout lines of the floor?

Tags: tiling

So in the picture below I am now installing the edging
Is it recommended to align the grout lines of the wall with the grout lines of the floor ?
So on the door wall I will have 3+1 cuts
On the other wall I will have 2 cuts
For edging I will I will use the same tile as for the floor
Update: here is what I decided to do
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe add a pic with the intended grout lines. As it stands, I don't see any and I'm having a hard time trying to envision where you're thinking of putting yours. It looks like you've got no grout lines at all, which would, I'd think, be the best option.

Comment: This is one of those questions that come down to if it bugs you or not.  If it bugs you that the lines do not line up, then try to line them up.  Would do a dry run with the easy way(not lining up) for a couple of days.  Keep looking at it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll look better if the grout lines up with that of the wall tiles, but they may be an odd size (too wide). Certainly line up *something* if you can. But often the edging won't allow lining up, due to different sizes. If not, don't bother.

Answer (score 1):

If your edging is a long strip with a bullnose top, I wouldn't be cutting it into sections if it can go edge to edge. If it's shorter pieces where a cut is needed, then I'd match the grout lines. If you do cut it, make sure the top edges are straight and any irregularities are at the bottom, which would be filled in with grout.

Answer (score 1):

If the edge tiles are the same width and pattern as the floor tiles you should match the grout lines.  If they are the actual floor tiles and not bullnose ones you should add an edging strip along the top edge.

If they are a different pattern (contrast) or if they are a different width you should not match the grout lines and you should not cut them unnecessarily.  In fact, you should if necessary cut one of the end edge tiles so that the non-matching grout lines do not appear to be slightly misaligned matching ones anywhere along the wall.

Exception: If the edge tiles are bullnose ones double the width of the floor ones in the same pattern as the floor ones, IMO you should cut them in half to match all the grout lines.

Comment: the edge tiles (strips) will be cut of the same tiles as the floor tiles just narrower strips. I guess I will do a dry fit to see what they look like, the problem is that if I match the lines on both walls I will have various cut sizes on the two walls (like 2' on the wall on the left and 1' on the wall on the right in the picture)

Comment: Can use something like cardboard or wood to cut and see, before cutting tiles to match.  Be looking at this for years, so try for best look(for you).

Comment: Oh you are right!  Your tiles are not square and you'll be matching the width on one wall and length on the other.  That might look stupid.  Or maybe it will look great.  I think @crip659 has offered a couple of good suggestions .... don't lock in til you're sure!

Comment: ok added the picture with a dry fit decided to align what I could and minimize the cuts so I aligned everything to 2' where it was possible

Comment: So this is what I was afraid of.  On the short side you have exactly one edge piece that aligns with exactly two tiles.  All the rest are partial hits.  I think, for what it's worth, that looks bad.    Since you only have room for one full lengthwise piece along that wall, I would not use any lengthwise pieces. Cut them all to match exactly the adjacent floor tiles.

Comment: Or maybe you could get two full lengthwise pieces in beginning with the right edge of the door and a tiny piece against the right wall, with no alignment at all with the floor.   That might work better.

Comment: not sure which one you call the short side, the right side is fine I am not going to chop those in smaller pieces ...I am ok with the current layout, my objective was to aligh as much as I could with minimal cutting

Comment: If you like it that's what counts here.